# How do I validate the contents of the Entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, tkinter-entry

In my Tkinter application I have an Entry widget and the user should fill it with numbers.

Is it possible to restrict the entered values to `int`, `float` and `long`?

Specifically, the user should only input a number:

- This can be `float`, `int`, `long`.
- The user can only put one `.` (a number doesn't have 2 dot anyway).

---

```
import tkinter as tk

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        vcmd = (self.root.register(self.on_validate), '%d', '%i', '%s', '%S')
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root, validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd)
        self.entry.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def on_validate(self, d, i, s, S,):
        if S == "-" and s.count('-') != 1 and int(i) == 0:
            return True
        if d == "0":
            return True
        try:
            return int(S) >= 0 and int(S) <= 9
        except:
            if S == "." and s.count('.') != 1:
                return True
            return False

app = App()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python/Tkinter: Interactively validating Entry widget content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot restrict the datatype, but you can restrict the characters that are allowed. See the answer to the question [Python/Tkinter: Interactively validating Entry widget content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/python-tkinter-interactively-validating-entry-widget-content)